# How do I make selections within a foreach loop work?

Tags: php, html

Each player has a playerID, and this is a selection table to change the team that the player was on. Each team is represented by it's color.... Blue,Yellow, Green, Red. I want to be able to change the players team... how would I do this?

I am bad at explaining so I hope I make sense :/

> ```
>               <th></th>
>               <th>Player</th>
>               <th>Team</th>
>               <th>Result</th>
>               <th>Kills</th>
>               <th>Deaths</th>
>               <th>DD</th>
>               <th>DT</th>
>               <th>RW</th> 
>               <th>RL</th>
>               <th>Session</th>
>
>               <? 
>
>               foreach($stats as $stat){ ?>
>
>               <tr>
>               <td><?=$stat->playerID;?></td>
>               <td> <?= $stat->getPlayerName($stat->playerID); ?> </td>
>
>
>               <td>
>               <? $player = $stat->playerID;?>
>               <select class="form-control" name="team">
>
>           <?  
>
>
>
>
>               echo "<option value='1'>Blue</option>";
>               echo "<option value='2'>Green</option>";
>               echo "<option value='3'>Red</option>";
>               echo "<option value='4'>Yellow</option>";
>                            ?>
>
>               </select>
>               </td>
>
>
>               <td> <?= $stat->pResult; ?> </td>
>               <td> <?= $stat->pKills; ?> </td>
>               <td> <?= $stat->pDeaths; ?> </td>
>               <td> <?= number_format($stat->pDmgDealt); ?> </td>
>               <td> <?= number_format($stat->pDmgTaken); ?> </td>
>               <td> <?= $stat->pRoundWin; ?> </td>
>               <td> <?= $stat->pRoundLose; ?> </td>
>               <td> <?= $stat->pSession . "m" ; ?> </td>   
>               </tr>   
>
>           <?              }           ?>
>
>
>           </table>
>
>           <input type="submit" name="subtest" value="Submit"/>
>
>           </form>
> ```

Comment: You should give your form fields array-style names like `name="team[]"`, then the form submission will contain an array of all the inputs. You should also include a hidden input that contains the team ID for each row.

Comment: @WojciechFrącz  

I named the select class ass follows:

name="team_<?php echo $stat->playerID?>"

and then...
$teamID = $_POST['team_'.$stat->playerID];
$playerID = $stat->playerID;

But that did not work.